# What exactly is not clear with this question?

Tags: discussion

[Which Sci-Fi work first showed this Black Hole graphics for FTL travel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/263668/931)

In this question, what exactly is not clear? There are FTL drives which use black holes, but I am looking for its subset in which a particular graphics is used.

What more clarification do you need?

Answer (score 6):

You start your question with

> Large number of Sci-Fi works make use of black holes for FTL travel

I don't know about "large number;" it's possible there are a few, but the only one I can think of is the KK drive from Foster's *Humanx* novels.  There are a bunch of cases where small black holes are used as power sources (e.g. *Imperial Earth*, Sheffield's "kernels") but most works hard enough to use a black hole as a power source are also usually hard enough not to permit FTL.

But you're asking about a visual, so presumably we must restrict ourselves to TV and movies, as well as comics or illustrated works.

Unfortunately you then confuse things with

> first used this Black Hole graphics created by FTL drive?

So now you're no longer just asking about naturally-occurring black holes, you're asking specifically about artificial black holes generated by an FTL drive.  *And* which must be depicted in the way pioneered in *Interstellar*.

Then you give us some examples.  *Foundation*'s jump drive, while FTL and gravitic, and having the correct effect, isn't obviously described as creating a black hole.  It's also not clear in the *Eternals* clip that it's FTL travel, as opposed to just a "leave the universe" effect, *or* that it's a black hole.  Even in *Interstellar* the black hole (which is natural) wasn't the means of travel, it was the wormhole in orbit that they used to travel between the Solar system and Gargantua's system.

So you're asking about the first occurrence of something that is so over-specified that you probably need to establish that there definitely is at least one instance in the first place.

Comment: I never talked about “naturally-occurring” black holes. And, I never used Interstellar in the question.

Comment: @SatelliteofSin Maybe if you did address artificial vs naturally occurring and the use of the graphics in *Interstellar*, it would help to clarify your question. The purpose of DavidW’s answer here is to tell you why your question is unclear. I think the point might be that you’re asking for the first occurrence of something that many of us aren’t sure has ever occurred even once. So adding some examples of where you think it has occurred might help us understand what you’re asking about.